# Empty space after a paragraph with { }

Tags: spacing

I want to add one blank space of line after I apply an independent centering as follows:

```
Bla bla bla. Figure 1 presents the results of the overall period: \\

{\centering [Insert Figure 1 here] \par} \\

Overall, the model seems to work well bla bla bla
```

While the first \ works and creates an empty line, the second \ does not seem to work. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should never use `\\ ` to end a paragraph! Use `center` environment instead of `\centering`. It already adds vertical space. Or (better) use a `figure` environment and [let the figure float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/).

Comment: The `\\ ` will have tex complaining about underfull hbox badness 10000, which is the _maximum_ badness. remove the `\\ ` the `\centering` and the `\par` and use `\begin{center}` which adds suitable space.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla. Figure 1 presents the results of the overall period: \\

{\centering [Insert Figure 1 here] \par} \\

Overall, the model seems to work well bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

The first `\\` produces the warning

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--6
```

which is the maximum level of badness reported by TeX. Never place a `\\` at the  end of a paragraph, it does not add vertical space it just forces the paragraph to have a spurious extra line with no content (hence the warning).

The second `\\` generates an error message,

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

Never ignore errors, the way TeX recovers from errors is only designed to allow the rest of the file to be checked for further errors, it is not designed to make sensible pdf output. The error here is because `\\` is following `\par` so specifying a line to end before the paragraph has started,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla. Figure 1 presents the results of the overall period: 

\begin{center}
[Insert Figure 1 here]
\end{center}

Overall, the model seems to work well bla bla bla

\end{document}
```