# I have a rogue '%' symbol beside a table. How do I remove it?

Tags: tables, formatting, pdftex, csvsimple

I am using the csvsimple package to read a csv, and am doing some minimal formatting in Latex. The csv consists of strings formatted as percentages.

I have created hacks to get around most of the problems, but now have a % symbol off to the side of my table. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{csvsimple} % Generates table from .csv

\newcommand{\csvloopx}[2][]{\csvloop{#1,#2}}
\newcommand{\csvautotabularx}[2][]{\csvloopx[#1]{autotabular={#2}}}
\newcommand{\respectpercent}{\catcode`\%=12\relax}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[H]

    \begin{center}
    \begingroup\catcode`"=9
     \csvreader[no head, tabular=|c|r|r|r|r|,%
        before table=\respectpercent,%
        table head=\hline \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Year}%
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Base}% 
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Round Lot \\ of 100 \\ Shares}% 
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Transaction Cost \\ of \$0.01 \\ per~Share}%  
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Transaction Cost \\ of \$0.01 \\ per Share and \\ Round Lot \\ of 100 Shares}\\\hline,% 
        late after line = \\\hline,%
            filter expr={
                test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}}]%
        {Figures/Document/Cost.csv}%
        {1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four, 5=\five}%
        {$\one$ & $\two$ & $\three$ & $\four$ & $\five$}%
    \endgroup
    \end{center}

    \caption{Market Cost Assumption}
    \label{ tab:Slippage}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

and the resulting table is

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the head of the csv file:

```
"Year","Base","RoundLot","TransactionCost","TransactionRoundLot"
2001,"3.41%","3.42%","3.35%","3.35%"
2002,"-10.46%","-10.45%","-10.50%","-10.49%"
2003,"22.58%","22.57%","22.53%","22.52%"
2004,"20.03%","20.02%","19.98%","19.97%"
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable.

Comment: Also, you should almost never use the `H` option. Why? See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats/370632#370632

Comment: I have already found that removing the comment symbol from the line {$\one$ & $\two$ & $\three$ & $\four$ & $\five$}% is solving the problem... but I am looking to find why this happens

Answer (score 6):

The problem happens because you tell LaTeX that `%` is not a comment character. Removing all of them (none was necessary in the code) fixes the issue.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
"Year","Base","RoundLot","TransactionCost","TransactionRoundLot"
2001,"3.41%","3.42%","3.35%","3.35%"
2002,"-10.46%","-10.45%","-10.50%","-10.49%"
2003,"22.58%","22.57%","22.53%","22.52%"
2004,"20.03%","20.02%","19.98%","19.97%"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{csvsimple} % Generates table from .csv

\newcommand{\respectpercent}{\catcode`\%=12\relax}
\newcommand{\ignoredblquote}{\catcode`\"=9\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\csvreader[
  no head,
  tabular=|c|r|r|r|r|,
  before table=\respectpercent\ignoredblquote,
  table head={
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Year} &
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Base} &
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Round Lot \\ of 100 \\ Shares} &
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Transaction Cost \\ of \$0.01 \\ per~Share} &
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Transaction Cost \\ of \$0.01 \\ per Share and \\ Round Lot \\ of 100 Shares} \\
    \hline
  },
  late after line = \\\hline,
  filter expr={
    test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}
  },
]{\jobname.csv}%
  {1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four, 5=\five}
  {$\one$ & $\two$ & $\three$ & $\four$ & $\five$}

\caption{Market Cost Assumption}
\label{tab:Slippage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I changed the name of the csv file just to make the example self contained. I also removed unused packages and commands for the same reason.

Avoid the `[H]` option. I also defined `\ignoredblquote` similarly to `\respectpercent`, so a group is not needed.

Note that a space in `\label` is not ignored.

[image]

Comment: The only % that causes the problem is the one after $\five$} .... All the other changes are good for the MWE but doesn't change the result... I can not understand why at that point a percent couses this problem... If you leave a space... it goes under the table... it has to do with the way csvsimple "closes" the table

Answer (score 0):

Rescue service:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
"Year","Base","RoundLot","TransactionCost","TransactionRoundLot"
2001,"3.41%","3.42%","3.35%","3.35%"
2002,"-10.46%","-10.45%","-10.50%","-10.49%"
2003,"22.58%","22.57%","22.53%","22.52%"
2004,"20.03%","20.02%","19.98%","19.97%"
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{csvsimple} % Generates table from .csv

\newcommand{\csvloopx}[2][]{\csvloop{#1,#2}}
\newcommand{\csvautotabularx}[2][]{\csvloopx[#1]{autotabular={#2}}}
\newcommand{\respectpercent}{\catcode`\%=12\relax}

\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\me}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[H]

    \begin{center}
    \me{\begingroup\catcode`"=9
     \csvreader[no head, tabular=|c|r|r|r|r|,%
        before table=\respectpercent,%
        table head=\hline \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Year}%
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Base}% 
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Round Lot \\ of 100 \\ Shares}% 
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Transaction Cost \\ of \$0.01 \\ per~Share}%  
                 & \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{\centering \bfseries Transaction Cost \\ of \$0.01 \\ per Share and \\ Round Lot \\ of 100 Shares}\\\hline,% 
        late after line = \\\hline,%
            filter expr={
                test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}}]%
        {\jobname.csv}%
        {1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four, 5=\five}%
        {$\one$ & $\two$ & $\three$ & $\four$ & $\five$}%
    \endgroup}%
    \end{center}

    \caption{Market Cost Assumption}
    \label{ tab:Slippage}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

This being said, I only fixed the `%` issue. Refer to @egreg's answer to the further needed improvements. I added package  `float` to make the example compilable and copied-over  `filecontents*` usage from @egreg's answer for the same reason.

As for the explanation it was given by @egreg. The `%` is set to not be a comment character when csvtable starts doing the table.

The earlier `%` were still comment characters when `\csvreader` fetched its arguments, hence behaved as such. With the `\me` method I am freezing the catcode of the last `%`, just to illustrate.

But much simpler is to use `\relax` in place of problematic `%` to gobble the end of line space (hmm... anyway the extra space token is removed by TeX when closing the paragraph, and your table is way too wide anyhow

```
Overfull \hbox (70.65941pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 40--42
```

)

The earlier ones are not needed as pointed out by @egreg. When a LaTeX command has N arguments given in brace pairs, intervening spaces are ignored... except if it is defined in some special way;  further, csvreader probably ignores spaces after commas when parsing comma separated options.