# Big gap under the subsection title

Tags: floats, pdftex

There is a big gap under the subtitle (second is ok and I want to gain the same result )even if I used to the same code for both subtitles .

```
\subsubsection*{Aviation}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}[H]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{jetplane_image&histogram.jpg}
\caption{Jetplane Image and Histogram}
\label{fig:3_9_14}
\caption*{Source: http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/root\_files\_V3/image\_databases.htm}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[H]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chemicalplant_image&histogram.jpg}
\caption{Chemical Plant Image and Histogram}
\label{fig:3_9_15}
\caption*{Source: https://processing.org/tutorials/color/}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\subsubsection*{Medical}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mri_image&histogram.jpg}
\caption{MRI Image and Histogram}
\label{fig:3_9_16}
\caption*{Source: http://www.cefns.nau.edu/\~pam7/EE442/grayscale/grayscaleimgs.html} 
\end{figure}
```

And results are following;

[image]
[image]

Can anybody help me? I know floating is a widespread problem and I checked the lots of documents but it does not make sense gaining different odd results via the same codes.

Comment: Just a general advice: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/124577

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The image in the link has errors and can't be displayed. However, I suspect the problem comes from the `[H]` specifier. It should be avoided as much as possible: a `figure` is a `floating` environment, that LaTeX  tries to place in the best possible way, according to its criteria.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Bernard actually, I tried to [h] and [h!]. I took the same results!