# Align center-align text in two columns under multicolumn

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

my table **right now looks like** this:
[image]

**I want** to center-align the text in the first two columns like how it is done with the other columns (sorry for the quick and dirty photoshop job):

[image]

I noticed that when I add vertical divider after the first and second column that the second column is much wider than the first column. To me that seems weird because the text in the columns is the same and also the Alignment.

My LaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{2}{r}{Long Word} & \phantom{a} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Another Word} \\\cmidrule{1-2}\cmidrule{4-7}
\makecell[c]{\\a} & \makecell[c]{\\a} & & \makecell[c]{word\\a} & \makecell[c]{word\\a} & \makecell[c]{word\\a}  & \makecell[c]{word\\ a} \\
\midrule
a & a & & a & a & a & a \\
a & a & & a & a & a & a \\
a & a & & a & a & a & a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Why aren't the two cells under "Long Word" together as wide as the "Long Word" cell? How can I achieve this?**

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why you use `\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}` instead `\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}`? Is this critical for you?

Comment: Please see also [Why the H option shouldn't be used for floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/124577).

Comment: Btw: You could help us help you by making your example compilable, i.e. add the documentclass and required packages. Furthermore you may delete some parts which are not needed to reproduce the problem (like `\hdashline`).

Comment: @sergiokapone Yes I would like to keep that.

Comment: @TeXnician Sorry, I edited my LaTex.

Comment: @DropArt: I don't really understand the problem. Is it because `Long Word` in the first row doesn't look centred w.r.t. the first two columns? Or do you  want the cells contents to be vertically centred in their row?

Comment: @Bernard I should look like the second image. The column type is `c`so the two columns under "Long Word" should together be as wide as "Long Word" and the text in the columns should be centered.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell, array, booktabs, arydshln}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Word} & {\phantom{a}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Another Word} \\\cmidrule{1-2}\cmidrule{4-7}
\makecell[c]{\phantom{word}\\a} & \makecell[c]{\phantom{word}\\a} & & \makecell[c]{word\\a} & \makecell[c]{word\\a} & \makecell[c]{word\\a}  & \makecell[c]{word\\ a} \\
\midrule
a & a & & a & a & a & a \\\hdashline
a & a & & a & a & a & a \\\hdashline
a & a & & a & a & a & a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but you should probably explain that the column's width was not sufficient and that you adjusted it.

Comment: It works, but only if the length of `\phantom{word}` and `\phantom{word}` is as long or longer than "Long Word". I think there is a better/cleaner solution to this. This seems more like a hack.

Comment: @DropArt if you use `\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}` the result result will look better

Comment: @sergiokapone Yeah it may look better in your opinion but that doesn't change that the two cells under "Long Word" together aren't as wide as the "Long Word" cell and the text in the cells isn't centered.

Answer (score 0):

I propose some improvements and simplifications. First I use only 6 columns, increasing  the horizontal spacing between columns  2 and 3 and playing with the `l` and `r` keys of `\cmidrule`. Also, you don't need  tu use the `[c]` option of `\makecell`, as it is the default (both vertically and horizontally). Last, I removed the modification of  ``\arraystretch`, since the rules from`booktabs`have some vertical paddind, and I think replacing the dashed lines of`arydshln`with`\addlinespace` loks nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{calc} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
\centering
 %\newlength\LWwidth
\settowidth{\LWwidth}{LongWord}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rc!{\hspace*{1pc}}*{4}{c}@{}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{ Long Word } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Another Word} \\\cmidrule(r{0.9pc}){1-2}\cmidrule(l{0.5pc}){3-6}
\makecell[r]{\hspace*{0.5\LWwidth}\\a} & \makecell {\hspace*{0.5\LWwidth}\\a} & \makecell {word\\a} & \makecell {word\\a} & \makecell {word\\a} & \makecell {word\\ a} \\
\midrule
a & a & a & a & a & a \\
\addlinespace
a & a & a & a & a & a \\
\addlinespace
a & a & a & a & a & a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]