# Figures keep appearing in a different place in the article then I meant.

Tags: floats, lyx, babel

I am using Lyx to write an article, and I use Hebrew.

When trying to insert a figure in a certain spot, it keeps appearing in a different position. I followed this guide https://www.lyx.org/Walkthrough3 exactly, but it just didn't work.

for example: I wrote a  paragraph, at the end of it I inserted a figure. then, when viewing the pdf, the figure keeps appearing at the beginning of the next page:

[image: as you can see, i inserted the figure after subsection 1.1]
but viewing the pdf, it looks like this:
[image: it isn't underneath subsection 1.1]
[image: it is just at the beginning of the next page.]

Comment: In LaTeX figure can "float". That's a feature not a bug. It avoids large white spaces. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats

Comment: You can right-click on the grey box with red text "float" and go to settings to change the default behavior. But if you don't want the image to "float", you could just not use a float.