# texstudio cref completion for labels in macros

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, texstudio, labels, auto-completion

Is there a way to have completion for cref references for labels defined in a command macro?

```
\newcommand{\midpict}[4]{    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#1}
                \caption{\label{fig:#4}#3} 
            \end{center} 
        \end{figure}
    \end{center}
}
```

I use it like

```
\midpict{./template/placeholder.png}{0.5}{This is a placeholder}{placeholder-img-1}
```

And I'd like to use `Cref{fig:placeholder-img-1}` but have the completion feature for this label.

Comment: What are you doing with that macro? Why are there two center envs? and why is that not floating? IMO you are better of making a template in your editor and have it fill in this code instead of attempting to get the editor to parse an extra macro in order to find the label.

Comment: You're right, the outer center environment isn't necessary. Can you specify what you mean by "making a template in my editor"?

Comment: Texstudio has an interface for making small templates that can be attached to a shortcut. That template will then insert the code and perhaps ask you for data to fill in the template, since I don't use texstudio I cannot provide more details, see the texstudio manual for information. What you're doing here is not generally recommended as it becomes hard to keep track up after a while.

Comment: Off-topic: The `center` environment will add additional spacing to your figure, better use `\centering` inside your figure.

Comment: And of course avoid `H` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats).

Comment: If you're willing to write the `fig:` part in your argument (i.e., not hide it in the definition for  the `\midpict` command, it's possible to have the correct label be recognized for cross-referencing in TeXstudio autocompleter. Alternatively, you can write a user macro in TeXstudio that inserts that chunk of code (in `\midpict`) with some combination of keystrokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably too late for OP, but for the record:

You can tell TeXstudio how to treat the arguments in your own commands by putting the definitions in `cwl` files. For your command the declaration should look something like this, if you want the label to be recognized

```
\midpict{imagefile}{rel. width}{caption%text}{label%labeldef}#g
```

However, this only works if you type the full label in the command, i.e. replace `\label{fig:#4}` with `\label{#4}` and type `fig:` when using the macro.

See also my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585485/163512).