# Table of Contents Spacing/Indentation

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, sectioning, positioning

I need help formatting my Table of Contents. All my sections have a roman numeral numbering system that I would like to keep but it does not space it right in the Table of Contents. I also prefer the subsubsection look over subsection but do not know how to move the subsubsection listings in the Table of Contents to the left (i.e. less indented). Here is my code (I left some unimportant stuff out - like the actual contents of each section):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{gensymb}  
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}  
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}  
\usepackage{indentfirst}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}  

% place figures and tables where it seems like they should be  
\usepackage{float}  
\floatplacement{figure}{H}  
\floatplacement{table}{H}  

% automatically center figures/tables  
\makeatletter  
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\centering}  
\makeatother  

\usepackage{tocvsec2}  
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=subsection]{hyperref}  
\usepackage{bookmark}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
% \usepackage{authblk}  
\usepackage{titling}  
\setlength{\droptitle}{-1in}  

\RequirePackage[style]{abstract}  
\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{}  
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalsize}  
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0.5in}  
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0.5in}  
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}  

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}  
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}  
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Fig.}}  
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{Table}}  

\pretitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{16pt}{1em}\bfseries\selectfont\vspace{14pt}}  

\newcommand\EatDot[1]{}  

\posttitle{\end{center}}  
\preauthor{\begin{center}\fontsize{12pt}{1.5em}\selectfont}  
\postauthor{\end{center}}  
\predate{\begin{center}}  
\postdate{\end{center}}  


\usepackage{titlesec}  
\titleformat{\subsection}[wrap]  
{\normalfont\bfseries}  
{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}  

% Better subsubsection formatting  
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}  

\usepackage{sectsty}  
\sectionfont{\centering\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\selectfont}  
\subsectionfont{\centering\fontsize{11pt}{1em}\selectfont}  
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{section}.\Alph{subsection}.}  
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{11pt}{1em}\selectfont}  
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{}  

% I have a bunch of title stuff here %

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\section{Technical Discussion of Approaches}

\section{Test Schedule}

\section{Equipment}

\subsubsection{Load Cell Calibration}
```

From this, my Table of Contents looks like:
[image: Code Output for Table of Contents]

I would also like if the TOC dots were for each section AND subsubsection. Right now, they only show up for the subsubsection listings. Also, as you can see, my preamble is very messy and some parts might be redundant. When I try to "clean it up", I get nasty failure errors. If you have suggestions there too, I would love to hear them. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should not use both `titlesec` and `sectsty`; as they tackle the same things.. Also, could you post a *compilable* code?

Comment: The overprinting of Roman numerals and TOC text is addressed in [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 1):

For the ToC use the `tocloft` package (`> texdoc tocloft` to read the manual). In your preamble put

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecdotsep}{4.5}  % use dots in the section entries
\renewcommand*{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em} % increase space for Roman numerals
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsubsecindent}{2em} % reduce indent of subsubsection titles
```

Adjust the 3em and 2em lengths to suit.

Not a good idea to use [H] floats see [Is float placement [H] considered heinous?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880)