# Two dots after "Table 1" in a table caption

Tags: tables, captions

In my latex file I use the following table

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r||r|r|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{|c||}{$\F \cong F_r$} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Generic $\F$}\\
\hline
$i$ & $i=0$ & $i=1$ & $i=0$ & $i=1$ \\
\hline
$0$ & $1$ & $0$  & $0$   & $0$   \\
$1$ & $r$ & $0$  & $r$   & $0$   \\
$2$ & $r$ & $1$  & $r-d$ & $0$   \\
$3$ & $1$ & $r$  & $d$   & $r$   \\
$4$ & $0$ & $r$  & $0$   & $r-d$ \\
$5$ & $0$ & $1$  & $0$   & $d$   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{My caption}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

But in pdf I'm getting two dots after Table 1:

[image]

Why is this happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome! It'd be helpful if you complete your code snippet to a minimal working example: a short document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and contains as few lines of code/text as are necessary to reproduce the issue. It is impossible to tell what the problem is from just this fragment.

Comment: Either you're loading `caption` package and have a strange `labelseparator` setup or `\thetable` is wrongly definied or uses `\Alph{...}` etc. printing nothing when the counter value is zero

Comment: @Alex: Please post either your working solution (cut down to the bare minimum such that it is compilable for others, of course) or delete the question...

Comment: Please don't use the [H] placement parameter. See [HEINOUS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880)