# subsection and subsubsection aren't working in elsevier template

Tags: floats, sectioning, errors, els-cas

I am working on Elsevier template with a single column format, I am facing an issue with subsections and subsubsections as they are displayed like a normal section with wrong numbering, for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\section{A}
dmddd
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}
\end{document}
```

It displays the following

1. A
2. AA
3. BB

===============================

Moreover, the figure's Specifier for positioning permission like H or h makes an error while compiling the document, for instance

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}                                        
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=60mm,width=140mm]{c}
\caption{ccc}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It displays this error:! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'cas/fig/H' is unknown and is being ignored.

Any help?

Comment: Can you supply us a minimal example that replicates this problematic behaviour? It'll give us some insight into how you're using the template and provide an opportunity to suggest alternatives/solutions.

Comment: Please provide a MWE that shows the problem. BTW using the [H] parameter for floats is not a good idea (see [Heineous]<https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880>

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}                                        \begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=60mm,width=140mm]{c}
\caption{ccc}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

It displays this error : ! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'cas/fig/H' is unknown and is being ignored.

Comment: @Werner : 
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}                                        \begin{document}
\section{A}
dmddd
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}
\end{document}

It displays the following 

1. A
2. AA
3. BB

Comment: I remember that some classes don't allow `\subsection` etc. and just redefine to be equal to `\section`. Perhaps `cas-sc` is an example of those

Comment: @GhadeerMobasher: Can you [edit your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/474109/edit) and add the content to your original post rather than in the comments? It allows for more characters and formatting...

Comment: I can't reproduce your font problem. For the position you can use `\begin{figure}[pos=H]`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your reply. However I don't have a font problem, my actual problem is that the subsection and subsubsection commands aren't worked as expected in this template. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue? TIA

Comment: Any help regarding the Subsection and Subsubsections issues?

Comment: To address a position of a figure, "\begin{figure}[pos=h]" worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Concerning the first part of your question:**

I'm not sure if this is by design (which would be a very odd behaviour), but this behaviour is caused by some redefinition in the class file. To workaround this problem one could fix these redefinitions and use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {10pt \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 2\p@}%
    {.1\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \ssectionfont\raggedright }}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {10pt \@plus 1\p@ \@minus .3\p@}%
    {.1\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \sssectionfont\raggedright}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}
\end{document}
```