# Placing a figure with subfigures immediately below paragraph title

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats, sections-paragraphs

I would like to have some paragraphs including a sequence of figures (no text at all). However I am not succeeding in placing the figures right below the paragraph title. What happens is that the paragraph title is shifted below the figures instead of remaining on top of those.

[image]

I know from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text) that I should not use a floating environment (such as the `figure` one) if I do not want my object to float in the document. However I need to organize my images in the same way I would do with the `figure` and `subfigure` environments. I have also tried using the `H` option, but it does not work. How can I achieve that?

Below a MWE for my case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}    % Images formatting
\usepackage{graphicx} % Insert figures
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{\boldmath$N=16$}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Illustration 1 of $N=16$}
\label{fig:ill1n16}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is enough: `newpage\paragraph{$\bm{N=16}$}
\leavevmode
\begin{figure}[H] .....`

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it truly minimal -- no need to have 6 `figure` environments over 2 pages if a singe `\paragraph` statement and a single `figure` environment will do too, right?

Comment: @Bernard - You should post the `\leavevmode` suggestion as an answer -- and maybe provide an insight as to how and why `\leavevmode` "works" here?

Comment: @Mico thanks for the suggestion, indeed a single `figure` environment does the job for the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figure or table environment requires to be in horizontal mode. Immediately after a \paragraph or \subparagraph command, you're in vertical mode. The `\leavevmode` command ensures you're no more in vertical mode, and if you add it in your code, like this:

```
\paragraph{\boldmath$N=16$}
\leavevmode
\begin{figure}[H]
 .........
```

it will work.

Comment: You wrote, "Immediately after a sectioning command, you're in vertical mode." This is a bit too broad -- the `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` commands appear to require `\leavevmode` for the problem at hand, whereas `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` do not.

Comment: Do not use the [H] float positioning parameter. See [HEINOUS]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880}

Comment: @PeterWilson: I know, but in the present case, I think it's inevitable considering the OP's requirements, so I respected his/her code.