# How can I get my table or figure to stay where they are, instead of going to the appendix or end of the document?

Tags: floats

[How can I get the figures not to be pushed to the end of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/how-can-i-get-the-figures-not-to-be-pushed-to-the-end-of-the-document)

I have visited the above link already and I tried what is said their, but failed to get my task done. 
My code is given below.
Please help me to get the figure, table on the place itself rather than letting it go to the end of the document.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{placeins}           

\title{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\shorttitle{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\author{You}
\affiliation{Somewhere}

\abstract{Your abstract here.}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}

    Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.
    If you have a question, please use the support box in the bottom right of the screen to get in touch. \citep{paper1}

    \section{Some \LaTeX{} Examples}
    \label{sec:examples}

    \subsection{Sections}

    Use section and subsection commands to organize your document. \LaTeX{} handles all the formatting and numbering automatically. Use ref and label commands for cross-references.

    \subsection{Comments}

    You can add inline TODO comments with the todonotes package, like this:
    \todo[inline, color=green!40]{This is an inline comment.}

    \subsection{References}

    LaTeX automatically generates a bibliography in the APA style from your .bib file. The citep command generates a formatted citation in parentheses \citep{Lamport1986}. The cite command generates one without parentheses. LaTeX was first discovered.

    \subsection{Tables and Figures}

    Use the table and tabular commands for basic tables --- see Table~\ref{tab:widgets}, for example. You can upload a figure (JPEG, PNG or PDF) using the files menu. To include it in your document, use the includegraphics command as in the code for Figure~\ref{fig:frog} below.


    % Commands to include a figure:
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{\label{fig:frog}This is a figure caption.}     
        \afterpage{\FloatBarrier}   
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|r}
            Item & Quantity \\\hline
            Widgets & 42 \\
            Gadgets & 13
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
    \end{table}

    \subsection{Mathematics}

    \LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
    $$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
    = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i$$
    denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

    \subsection{Lists}

    You can make lists with automatic numbering \dots

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Like this,
        \item and like this.
    \end{enumerate}
    \dots or bullet points \dots
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Like this,
        \item and like this.
    \end{itemize}

    We hope you find write\LaTeX\ useful, and please let us know if you have any feedback using the help menu above.

    \bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the figure and tables env the `[htbp] ` option. I would not recommend the **right here** approach. Learn to use float properly, and accept that they flow around. If they go to the end of the doc/chapter, you're probably using the wrong gloat options.

Comment: I tried to run your example to debug the float placement but it produces the error `! File ended while scanning use of \efloat@xfloat.` and no output.

Comment: If I fix that it produces the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.7         \afterpage`  please don't ignore errors, the pdf output is not usually usable after an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `apa6` If you check the documentation (`texdoc apa6`) section 6.2 you will see that the `man` option that you are using moves all floats to the end of the document as that is a requirement for journals that use that setting. For drafting you can use the option `floatsintext` to disable this feature and leave floats where they are in the source.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{placeins}           

\title{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\shorttitle{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\author{You}
\affiliation{Somewhere}

\abstract{Your abstract here.}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}

    Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.
    If you have a question, please use the support box in the bottom right of the screen to get in touch. \citep{paper1}

    \section{Some \LaTeX{} Examples}
    \label{sec:examples}

    \subsection{Sections}

    Use section and subsection commands to organize your document. \LaTeX{} handles all the formatting and numbering automatically. Use ref and label commands for cross-references.

    \subsection{Comments}

    You can add inline TODO comments with the todonotes package, like this:
    \todo[inline, color=green!40]{This is an inline comment.}

    \subsection{References}

    LaTeX automatically generates a bibliography in the APA style from your .bib file. The citep command generates a formatted citation in parentheses \citep{Lamport1986}. The cite command generates one without parentheses. LaTeX was first discovered.

    \subsection{Tables and Figures}

    Use the table and tabular commands for basic tables --- see Table~\ref{tab:widgets}, for example. You can upload a figure (JPEG, PNG or PDF) using the files menu. To include it in your document, use the includegraphics command as in the code for Figure~\ref{fig:frog} below.


    % Commands to include a figure:
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}
        \caption{\label{fig:frog}This is a figure caption.}     
%        \afterpage{\FloatBarrier}   
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|r}
            Item & Quantity \\\hline
            Widgets & 42 \\
            Gadgets & 13
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}

    \subsection{Mathematics}

    \LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
    $$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
    = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i$$
    denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

    \subsection{Lists}

    You can make lists with automatic numbering \dots

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Like this,
        \item and like this.
    \end{enumerate}
    \dots or bullet points \dots
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Like this,
        \item and like this.
    \end{itemize}

    We hope you find write\LaTeX\ useful, and please let us know if you have any feedback using the help menu above.

    \bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm this solution works for `apa7` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *float* package? And **H** option in the figure?

```
\usepackage{float}

...

\begin{figure}[H]
```

[Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8633/181491)

Comment: Please don't use the H option unless you really know what you are doing. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880

Comment: did you check that this is compatible with apa6?