# Is there a way to permanently change what a command does in Overleaf?

Tags: graphics

I include a lot of images in my documents. Whenever I want to create a new one, I type `\begin {figure}` and the following auto-completes:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

What I have to do everytime is then go in and change it to:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

Can I automate it to include the `[H]` and `[width=\textwidth]`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I don't put [H], my images get out of order. If there's a different way to fix that I'm all ears. Usually I keep my graphics at ```0.9\textwidth```.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my question was generalized to specifying parameters to certain commands. If I can automate that, my setup works great for me regardless of how LaTex is supposed to work. Edit: I've been using ```figure``` because the Overleaf docs recommended to do that. I'll look into how else images can be inserted.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on Overleaf's editor to autocomplete the environment in some particular way. Say, if you have to change something in the general setup, then you have to change it manually in the whole document. Define a command `\myfigure{...}` or an environemnt `\begin{myfigure}...\end{myfigure}`, where all the shared definitions are contained in the definitions `\newcommand\myfigure}[1]{.... here ...}` or `\newenvironment{myfigure}{... here ...}{... here ...}`. Then, if the layout changes, you just have to modify these definitions.

Comment: LaTeX prints figures in the order they appear in your manuscript. Please don't use the `[H]` option; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880.