# Figure positioning with H

Tags: floats

I would like to set an automatic new page if there is no space to include the picture. I mean that if I do not include the figure there a thin space between the captions, but if I use the figure with H it force to include the figure to the defined position, but because of this latex make a wider space between the captions. I do not want this, I want a page break and the default space between the captions and include the figure to the defined position.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapter/chapter1}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex

```
\section{few}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\subsection{Alad}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \includegraphics{images/JS.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\section{ew}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you add `\raggedbottom` just before `\begin{document}`, does that help? With `twoside` LaTeX will try to fill the entire text block vertically, by stretching vertical space. When you have a big figure that doesn't quite fit on a page like that, it has to stretch a lot. With `\raggedbottom` you turn off that behaviour. (Incidentally, this is precisely why LaTeX lets figures float by default, to avoid that kind of thing.)

Comment: I cannot get your code to not produce what you have desired. It seems to work? I tried scaling the picture to get it on the first page and comparing it to when its too large, the caption distance appears to remain the same.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It is working, thanks

Comment: Oh you must have meant the spacing following the section headings. In either case, in the future you can use the `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\lipsum[number or range]` to produce fake text.

Comment: You shouldn't use `[H]` at all but let the figure be placed automatically. Anyway if you put a `\clearpage` just before the figure you will get the result you are looking for.

Comment: @Bob No, the choice is to *never* use `[H]`, unless you are an experienced user and know what you're doing and why.

Comment: Do not use `[H]`. See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469880