# How to prevent additional space after a table?

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

I have a table and I was not able to remove additional space that exists after the table's caption.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\raggedright
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
     ...
    \hline
\end{tabular}
 \caption{Notations used in the calculation of the cost function.}\label{cost:calc}
\end{table}
```

Example view:

[image]

How could I prevent additional space generated after a table?

Comment: Could you please add a compilable example code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: The spacing might depend on the documentclass and the packages you use. Therefore please make your code a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I have generated a minimal working example where the problem is fixed I am not sure why. But on my original work which is around 1500 lines, the problem still emerges. @leandriis

Comment: @alper: In this case, make a copy of your original file and start commenting out some lines of code, recompile and see if the issue persists. Continue to remove unnecessaray lines of code until you have the smallest document possible that still recreates your problem.

Comment: Replacing `\begin{table}[ht]` into `\begin{table}[H]` fixed the problem.  @leandriis

Comment: @alper: You might be interested in [Why should the “H” option not be used in floats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/134144)

Comment: Often situations like this arise when LaTeX adjusts the space between elements on the page in order to make the page breaks fall at "acceptable" spots. This might explain why the problem doesn't occur when you include only a small amount of text (=> no page break).