# Inserting images using Overleaf

Tags: floats

I am trying to insert images but they appear in unexpected places. They keep appearing at the bottom of the paragraph while I need them to appear where I inserted them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\section{standing wave}

\subsection{Standing Wave Concept}
\textbf{What is exactly a Standing Wave?}\\


lets say we initiated a pulse through a  fixed end rope .
(\textbf{Figure 1})\\

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{Screenshot (199).png}
    \caption{Wave in a fixed end rope}
    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The main point of a float environment like figure is to let them float away. And the main point of a \label is to allow to reference them, even if they are on the next page. So remove the [h], let them float and use `As seen in figure~\ref{fig:my_label} ...`. And don't end paragraphs with `\\ `, this will only give warnings. If you absolutly don't want them to float you can use the float package and [H], but see here first https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370654/2388

Comment: I have updated my code but it gives me a number( number 1) in the correct place it doesn't display the picture, so how to display it.@UlrikeFischer

Comment: Don't use spaces in images file names.

Comment: will rename it but the main problem now is that I am getting a number not the picture so how to get to display the picture.@Zarko

Comment: We haven9t any information about document, so we can only guessing what you doing wrong. You my have `draft` option at `\documentclass`,  who knows. Please provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclas[...]{...}` and ending by `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: done! please review the code@Zarko

Comment: I re-edited the code, I want the picture in place not a reference to this picture so I used [h] and removed the \label but still, it doesn't appear in place @Zarko

Comment: "h" doesn't mean "here", it only means "here if possible". If you want "really here", then you need to use "H" (with \usepackage{float}).

Comment: With given document example, I cant reproduce your problem. Do you receive any errors or warning at compilation of your document? Show us result of your compilation of shoved document example, please.

Comment: Instead of `H`, you can forget the `figure` environment and use something like `{\par\centering\includegraphics{...}\captionof{figure}{.....}\par}` (you have to load package caption).

Comment: I suggest to read an introduction to LaTeX.