# Text jumps into the middle of the page because of a graph that follows

Tags: spacing, graphics, text, section-titles

I'm writing the "results" section where I have small descriptions and graphs. I want to have a \section(blabla) followed by a small text and then the graph. Right now I do have a \section(blabla), then a huge space(automatically generated), then the text (approx. in the middle) and on the bottom the graph. How can I have the text right beneath the section title? It looks really weird with such a huge space...Thank you!

Code:

```
\section{Comparison of graphs}
In figure \ref{fig:gnorm_levels}, \ref{fig:shear_levels} and \ref{fig:compression_levels} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris varius magna ipsum. Curabitur vel tortor nec ipsum pulvinar lobortis ut eu tortor. Phasellus rhoncus dolor nunc, eget pellentesque magna egestas in. Donec convallis finibus molestie. Nulla iaculis orci sit amet vehicula porttitor. Praesent mattis vehicula purus id ultrices. Vestibulum ex orci, imperdiet at fermentum vel, maximus sed diam. 

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=8cm]{graphics/levels.png}
\caption{Comparison}
\label{fig:gnorm_levels}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! It's impossible to say what's happening if you do not show an example. But as a wild guess: continue writing, and do not worry about figure placement until you have quite a good amount of text. If you used a correct command to place your floating elements, LaTeX will sort it out. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat also.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now :)

Comment: Try not to use `H`. That *will* create ugly space. `htb` is much better; the figure will be placed "here" if it fits without ugly spaces, and will float around if the need arise. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats

Comment: nice input, thanks!