# Placement of images keeps changing

Tags: graphics, floats

I am having a lot of trouble placing images where I want them in my document. With the first 3 images the it stops working. I am new to latex and still struggling to learn it. I have included the initial commands too.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

The code I used to display the image where I want it

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=15cm]{all_sky_map.png}
    \caption{All sky map}
    \label{fig:all sky map}
\end{figure}

This is the image
```

[image: All sky map]

```
This bit of code does not work and does not display the image where I want it

\subsection{Producing peaks in a spectrum}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{peaks_spectrum_1.png}
    \caption{Peaks in HI 21-cm Spectrum at (26.76, -1.54)}
    \label{fig:peaks spectrum}
\end{figure}
```

and this is the image used in the second bit of code
[image: peaks spectrum]

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should provide complete small document which reproduce your problem.  From showed fragment can not be concluded, that i anything wrong with your figures.

Comment: the figure is included by `\includegraphics`  that never moves. You have also used `figure`, the only purpose of the `figure` environment is to allow the figure to move to help with page breaking, but you have restricted the places it can move to you should normally iue `[htbp]` (or no option) rather than `[h]`. Your question is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: It is one of the features of LaTeX that figures can float. The rules are described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388. You can use the float package and its H option to prevent it, you can read about the pros and cons here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/2388

Comment: my problem got solved after i removed \beginfigure command