# Why is my paragraph appearing before the picture

Tags: overleaf

```
\begin{figure} [!h]
\includegraphics[width=140mm]{image9.png}
\caption{Columns in our dataset}
\label{fig:method}
\end{figure}

Since there are many columns, in order to decide which columns to include in the model, we selected relevant columns and created a correlation matrix using Minitab for both Uber and Lyft.

\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics[width=140mm]{image14.png}
\caption{Correlation matrix for Uber}
\label{fig:method}
\end{figure}
```

I want the text to appear between the two images but for some reason it is moving my text above the first picture. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you show what is above that first picture, or include all your `tex` file if possible?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  We need some more information.  Some document classes prohibit a float (figure or table) at the top of the first page, so at the very least, we need to know what document class you're using.  Ideally, a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem should be provided, so potential helpers can copy and paste to experiment.

Comment: Hi, @Simran Parajulee, and welcome to TeX.Se. Please, read about [Example images in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/140133) and also about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133)s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible alternative to your problem could be to add in your preamble the package \usepackage{float} and change [!h] to [H], this manages to control the location of the graphs and tables, but it depends on the type of document and . Try to do this in your document, otherwise we appreciate if you share all your compilable code.

```
 \begin{figure} [H]
    \includegraphics[width=140mm]{image9.png}
    \caption{Columns in our dataset}
    \label{fig:method}
    \end{figure}
    
    Since there are many columns, in order to decide which columns to include in the model, we selected relevant columns and created a correlation matrix using Minitab for both Uber and Lyft.
    
    \begin{figure}[H`enter code here`]
    \includegraphics[width=140mm]{image14.png}
    \caption{Correlation matrix for Uber}
    \label{fig:method}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Please, read [Why should the "H" option not be used in floats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370632/140133).